# Execute dynamic query that executes another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
DECLARE @TaskId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @TaskName VARCHAR(255) = 'MasterSet'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @StartingDateTask DATETIME2 = (SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
                                       FROM [TaskStatusAudit]
                                       WHERE [TaskId] = 'A1FDFC16-904D-4560-B19D-5E7D4FEB1C2B'
                                         AND [TaskStatusName] = 'IN-PROGRESS')

DECLARE @EndingDateTask DATETIME2 = (SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
                                     FROM [TaskStatusAudit]
                                     WHERE [TaskId] = 'A1FDFC16-904D-4560-B19D-5E7D4FEB1C2B'
                                       AND [TaskStatusName] = 'COMPLETED')

 SET @sql = N'SELECT dbo.TotalMinuteRange(@StartingDateTask,@EndingDateTask) as ' + quotename(@TaskName) + N''

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Problem is when I execute it I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@StartingDateTask".

Any ideas why I getting that if I declare my variable correctly? Regards

Comment: It should also be mentioned that you are using top 1 with no order by. If your query returns more than 1 row you can't ensure which is going to be returned. And if it can only return a single row the top 1 is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing sp_executesql you need to declare and pass the variables to sp_executesql something like..

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT dbo.TotalMinuteRange(@StartingDateTask,@EndingDateTask) as ' 
         + quotename(@TaskName) + N''


 exec sp_executesql   @sql
                    , N'@StartingDateTask DATETIME2 , @EndingDateTask DATETIME2'
                    , @StartingDateTask 
                    , @EndingDateTask
```

Second parameter is the variable declaration parameter followed by the actual variables separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like taking a parameters variable and assign it.

declare @params nvarchar(100)
set @params='@StartingDateTask DATETIME2,@EndingDateTask DATETIME2'

SET @sql = N'SELECT dbo.TotalMinuteRange(@StartingDateTask,@EndingDateTask) as ' 
         + quotename(@TaskName) + N''

exec sp_executesql   @sql
                    , @params
                    , @StartingDateTask 
                    , @EndingDateTask